# Is there a way to deference a struct as a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

#### Purely experimental

Before we jump in, this is purely experimental and I don't care about undefined behaviours.

Using `clang 13`.

#### My code

```
typedef struct {
    char *chr;
    int64_t len;
} string;

string str;
 
int main() {
    str.chr = "ABCDE";
    str.len = 6;

    printf ("str.chr  = %p\n", str.chr);
    printf ("str      = %p\n", str);
}
```

#### Output

```
str.chr  = 0x5c0845c56e // same address
str      = 0x5c0845c56e // same address
```

I want to do something like `*str`. This'd be equivalent to `*(0x5c0845c56e)`. So `str` is basically used as a pointer to the string.

Ofc, the compiler throws an error at that

```
error: indirection requires pointer operand ('string' invalid)
   printf ("*str      = %c\n", *str);
                               ^~~~
```

I've tried casting `str` to `void *` and `char *` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Line numbers in code just make it a chore to copy/paste/compile. You might consider removing them.

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: "I don't care about undefined behaviours" You should. Luckily, C guarantees the layout of its structs, so you're actually OK to assume that the char pointer is the first element in memory of `string`.

Comment: No C does not work this way. If you need `str.chr` say `str.chr`. if you need `*str.chr` say `*str.chr`.

Comment: FWIW, `printf ("str = %s\n", *((char **) &str));` *does* work.

Comment: In C++, you could overload `operator *`, in plain C, you could have a macro such as `#define STRING_PTR(s) (s.chr)` and then you could write `printf ("str      = %c\n", *STRING_PTR(str));`

Comment: @mvidelgauz I was thinking the same about using a macro. Note that `(s.chr)` ought to be `((s).chr)` for macro safety.

Comment: @IanAbbott you may be right, I thought that parentheses around the whole `s.chr` are enough. Also, instead of macro, we could use an (inline?) function that returns a pointer, but that would push the entire struct to stack (unless optimized by the compiler)

Comment: @mvidelgauz Well if you had `string *p = &str; char *s = STRING_PTR(*p);` it would expand to `string *p = &str; char *s = (*p.chr);` which would produce a compiler error. Using an inline function seems reasonable, assuming the compiler can optimize it well.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, you are right, those additional parentheses are necessary, thank you for the heads-up ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do something like `*str`. This'd be equivalent to
> `*(0x5c0845c56e)`. So `str` is basically used as a pointer to the
> string.

But `str` is *not* a pointer.  It is a structure.  To answer the titular question, **no, there is no way in C to dereference a value of structure type**.

> Ofc, the compiler throws an error at that
>
> ```
> error: indirection requires pointer operand ('string' invalid)
>    printf ("*str      = %c\n", *str);
>                                ^~~~
> ```

As I said, you cannot dereference a structure.

> I've tried casting `str` to `void *` and `char *` but that doesn't
> work.

Of course not.  C does not define any conversions between structures and pointers.

I guess you must be trying to draw an analogy with arrays, but their behaviors simply are not analogous.  However, if you want the *first* member of your structure then you can use the `&` operator to obtain the structure's address, convert it to a pointer to the type of the first member, and dereference *that* to get an lvalue representing the first member:

```
    printf ("str      = %c\n", *(*(char **)&str));
    // here ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But inasmuch as that depends on knowing the structure type's definition (to get the pointer conversion correct), it provides no advantage whatever over accessing the first member in the standard way:

```
    printf ("str      = %c\n", *str.chr);
```

Answer (score 1):

str is not declared as a pointer so you cannot dereference it using *.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    char *chr;
    int64_t len;
  } string;

  string str;

  int main () {

    int s = sizeof(char *);
    str.chr = "ABCDE";
    str.len = 6;

    printf ("str.chr  = %llu\n", &str.chr);  //address of str.chr
    printf ("char *      = %llu\n", &str);  //first 8 bytes of str structure
 }
```

output

```
@home:~$ ./a.out
str.chr  = 94437003264064
char *      = 94437003264064
```